# Windows Named Pipes Example not working on vmware windows machines

Tags: c#, windows, vmware, named-pipes

I am using this named pipes example

http://tech.pro/tutorial/633/interprocess-communication-using-named-pipes-in-csharp

It seems to work well on a physical installed machine but every time I try to use the client and server on vmware windows machine it fails.

Tried searching Google and the only thing that keep coming up is how to use named pipes to connect to another vmware machine.

I am trying to get 2 inter processes to communicate using pipes.

Is there a known reason why this dos not work?

I am using Vmware 9.X  tried it with XP vmware and windows 8 vmware.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see how this could be a virtualization issue. Try and open a support request at VMware.

Comment: A user of my application is running into the same/similar issue. We have .NET/C# app that successfully uses pipes on hundreds of Windows, but for some reason one VMWare Windows 7 32-bits installation pipes fail. Under the hood, we use same/similar pipes wrapper.

Comment: I had to scrape the code I was using that I found on the internet.  Imagine that your running into the same problem that I found before.  Here is a trick..  Go to google.com and search for some of the code your currently using and look for open source projects that have already fixed this issue.  In the end this is what I had to do.